# Why does "height: 1%" fix this issue in my flex-box-layout?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In this pen/fiddle I created a very, very simple page layout for demonstration purposes: [See Pen/Fiddle here!](https://codepen.io/ChrisVomRhein/pen/EvzYwy)

In the light blue "content"-area I have a div with class `flex-container` which holds a title and a div-nested image.

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <h1>Nice Image</h1>
      <div>
        <img src="http://loremflickr.com/800/800" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The issue I ran into was that whenever I set the images parent-div height in line 53 to 100%, the image would flow over. I started playing around with it, and as soon as I set the height to anything less than 100%, the image nicely scales to fit the remaining height of the div, i.e. the area taken up by the flex-growing parent div.

```
  .content {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3);
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    .flex-container {
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);

      >div {
        flex-grow: 1;
        height: 1%;
      }

      img {
        height: 100%;
      }
    }
  }
```

I am wondering why this is? This approach does not feel very clean, and I am wondering how I could improve that layout to make it feel less "hacky".

**Full HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Nav</div>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <h1>Nice Image</h1>
      <div>
        <img src="http://loremflickr.com/800/800" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="status">
    <p>Status: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Full SCSS:**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul, h1, p, img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;  
}

.container {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 38px 0px 30px 161px;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  .header {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 38px;    
  }

  .nav {
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    width: 161px;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .content {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3);
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    .flex-container {
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);

      >div {
        flex-grow: 1;
        height: 1%;
      }

      img {
        height: 100%;
      }
    }
  }

  .status {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.3);
    position: fixed;
    left: 161px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
  }
}
```

Comment: when you set an height value to your div and reset it flex-grow to 1 height is updated to fill room left . It allows the child to have an update on height's parent value. remove flex or height , and it breaks again. both rules are needed ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I started playing around with it, and as soon as I set the height to anything less than 100%, the image nicely scales to fit the remaining height of the div...

Actually, that's not entirely correct.

The image fits perfectly when the height is set to anything less than 96%.

This is because there are two items occupying space in the container: the title and the image.

The title is taking up 5% of the height. This leaves 95% for the image.

Anything above 95% overflows.

Anything less than 95% fits perfectly because `flex-grow: 1` is set to consume free space. Without `flex-grow` the image container would shrink accordingly.

Add a border around your image for a clear illustration of this behavior ([revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RZmGww)).

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that if your flex item (the `flex-container`'s `div` child) doesn't have a height, and when you give the `img` a height of 100%, it doesn't have from where to calculate that, hence the `img`'s will take its original size.

*Note, the `flex-grow: 1` doesn't give it one, it simply tells the flex item to fill the remaining space*

Update

The below suggestion with an extra wrapper appears to only work on Chrome, so I suggest you keep the set height for now, and I will update this when I know more.

<strike>So you can either keep its height, or you can add a wrapper for the `img` and make the `flex-container`'s `div` child a flex container.</strike>

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul, h1, p, img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 38px 0px 30px 161px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container .header {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 38px;
}
.container .nav {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 161px;
  height: 100%;
}
.container .content {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container .content .flex-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.container .content .flex-container > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}
.container .content .flex-container img {
  height: 100%;
}
.container .status {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.3);
  position: fixed;
  left: 161px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Nav</div>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <h1>Nice Image</h1>
      <div>
        <div>
          <img src="http://loremflickr.com/800/800" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="status">
    <p>Status: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey LGSon, thanks. However, I'm not quite sure if I got you right. All parents of the img element do have a specified height, don't they? html, body, .container, .flex-container, .flex-container > div and .flex-container > div > img have. So what is the difference?

Comment: @Christian In your original code the `flex-container > div` has a height (`1%`) but when you remove that the image doesn't scale, right? ... so after you remove it, that `img` wrapper doesn't have a height, hence it won't work. ... Or did you mean my solution?

Comment: @Christian I changed my answer slightly, so it instead says something like _if you not give it a height..._

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Thats true. I'm wondering, though, why setting `.flex-container > div` to `height: 100%` does not work. And also, I don't understand, why `height: 1%` fixes the issue, whereas I would expect the image to become super small!

Comment: @Christian That is the effect of the `flex-grow`. Delete it and you'll see it becomes supersmall

Comment: Okay, I see. But then, why does `flex-grow: 1` not affect the `height: 100%`?

Comment: @Christian Because it fills the height as flex-grow: 1 does, so you won't notice

Comment: @Christian I was doing a check cross browser and just noticed, my suggestion with a wrapper as is, only work on Chrome, so I suggest you keep the set height